# Como criar um PDF a partir de uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

quero criar um PDF a partir de uma lista porém esta resultando o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\nicperei\Desktop\pyCodes>py web.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 22, in <module>
    pdf.drawString(100, 10, listaFinal)
  File "C:\Users\nicperei\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 1560, in drawString
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

C:\Users\nicperei\Desktop\pyCodes>
```

segue meu código:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

url ='http://servicos2.sjc.sp.gov.br/servicos/horario-e-itinerario.aspx?acao=p&opcao=1&txt='

r = requests.get(url)
listaFinal = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
lista_intinerarios = soup.find_all('table', class_='textosm')
urlsjc = 'http://www.sjc.sp.gov.br'
for lista_td in lista_intinerarios:
    lista = lista_td.find_all('td')
    for lista_dados in lista:
        if lista_dados.next_element.name == 'a':
            url_it = '{0}{1}'.format(urlsjc,lista_dados.next_element.get('href'))
            listaFinal.append(url_it)
        else:
            listaFinal.append(lista_dados.next_element)

pdf = canvas.Canvas("Site_Prefeitura3.pdf")
pdf.drawString(100, 200,listaFinal)
pdf.save()

print(listaFinal)
print("Executado com sucesso...")
```

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O erro diz que a função `pdf.drawText` recebe apenas 2 argumentos, mas você passou 4.

Comment: Eu mudei de `pdf.drawText` para `pdf.drawString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então você tem que iterar sua lista, veja esse exemplo simples

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

listaFinal = ['oi', 'eu', 'sou', 'goku']

pdf = canvas.Canvas("Site_Prefeitura3.pdf")
for cont, l in enumerate(listaFinal):
    # Lembre de mudar a posição para não sobrepor uma string com outra da lista
    pdf.drawString(100, 300-15*cont,l)
pdf.save()
```

Caso o arquivo precise ter mais de uma página você pode usar a função `pdf.showPage()`. Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
pdf = canvas.Canvas('paginas.pdf')

pdf.drawString(100, 100, "Primeira página")
pdf.showPage()

pdf.drawString(200, 100, "Segunda página")
pdf.showPage()

pdf.drawString(300, 100, "Terceira página")
pdf.showPage()

pdf.save()
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Comment: ele não imprime todos os dados e só cria uma folha PDF, como poderia pra fazer pra colocar todos os dados e gerar mais páginas?

Comment: Olá Nicolas, veja na edição, um simples exemplo de como tu pode criar o pdf com mais de uma página.

Comment: Obrigado otavio!!